# Retrieve Salesforce Page layouts using python

Tags: python, layout, deployment, salesforce, sfdc

what i am trying to do is retrieving Salesforce page layouts as XML file using python, i have tried using SFDCLIB , Salesforce_API, simple_Salesforce but still unable to figure out a way to do that, have anyone ever tried to do that? or anyone have any clue about how to achieve that, kindly guide me through the process. i just need to successfully submit the retrieve request, kindly help.

Comment: Could you provide some code of what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible via simple_salesforce, the below example assumes we're using contacts

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
sf = Salesforce(username='username@username.com', password='XpasswordX', security_token='XtokenX', sandbox=False)

#this is a specific contact record type id as layouts depend on the record type
record_type_id = '01258023423c9gYBAQ'

layout = sf.Contact.describe_layout(record_type_id)
```

This will give you a json version of the data rather than xml but the structure is the same as what's shown here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_layouts.htm

Example `layout['buttonLayoutSection']`

Comment: Basically i am trying :
1.) retrieve Salesforce metadata using python (Like we retrieve using ant/eclipse)
2.) modify the extracted xml (this not necessarily will be done using python)
3.)deploy the modified metadata to org.
the approach which you mentioned i have tried but this just reads out the metadata, i can create and XML using output redirection (e.g. c:\\users\my_user>python my_file.py> object_layout.xml / object_layout.json) but this does not exactly follow the algorith which i am trying to use, thanks anyway, please let me know if you find anything more.

Comment: also i am avoiding any id to be mentioned in the code, but let's see if anything works out for me.

Comment: Hi i was able to make a retrieve request and success fully able to get the layouts extracted, but the output come like below, but i need to get the actual zip file, is there any way to get the original zip file from below content?
<zipFile>UEsDBBQACAgIAEtpqlAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwAAAAdW5wYWNrYWdlZC9sYXlvdXRzL0FjY291bnQtQWNjb3VudCBMYXlvdXQubGF5b3V07VtRc9o4EH7vr8jk/TDJ9Xp3HUrHcZyGnoOpba7tEyNsAb7IEpXkJNyvP1k22IADJsUy7VweEqxd7e63K69Wi9J5/xShswdIWUjwu/OLVvv8DGKfBCGevjsfeje//HH+vvuqY4EFifmZYMbs3fmM8/lbTWMEzFtsQqgPWz6JtMt2+43Wfq1FkIMAcHDefXUmfjrwyUdxAK9izglmXTceRyHvaBvDKS+Silzo8..
..
..
.
</zipFile>

Comment: Did you get the zipfile element from the json object (after converting) to xml? It looks like the zipfile is encoded in some way probabably base64

Comment: hey figured out,it was a silly one, had to give proper destination  i was able to extract the zip file and get the metadata, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: hey, i kind of ran into some other issue regarding this same requirement, i am having hard times deploying the retrieved metadata using python, i was using SfdcMetadataapi module to deploy, but it's not working showing error, does anyone have any information about how to deploy a package into Salesforce using python?